# Optimization of Linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm looking to optimize this query which is taking 4 seconds to execute on the ToList (according to ANTS). It looks fairly simple and I'm unsure as to why it's taking so long.

Help appreciated :)

```
public virtual List<Attendee> GetLiveByBookingId(int bookingId, Entities context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            context = new Entities(connectionString);
            context.Attendee.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
        }

        return GetLiveByBookingIdCompiledQuery().Invoke(context, bookingId).ToList();
    }

    private Func<Entities, int, IQueryable<Attendee>> GetLiveByBookingIdCompiledQuery()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Application["Attendee.GetLiveByBookingId"] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Application["Attendee.GetLiveByBookingId"] = CompiledQuery.Compile<Entities, int, IQueryable<Attendee>>(
                            (ctx, id) => (from a in ctx.Attendee
                                                  .Include("AttendeeTicket")
                                                  .Include("AttendeeDay")
                                                  .Include("Contact")
                                                  .Include("Contact.Address")
                                                  .Include("Contact.ContactClientCustomFieldValue")
                                                  .Include("Reservation")
                                                  .Include("Reservation.AccommodationRoomTypeNight.AccommodationRoomType")
                                                  .Include("AttendeeBookableSessionSignup")
                                                  .Include("AttendeeCustomFieldValue")
                                          where a.Booking.BookingId == id
                                          && !a.StatusIsDeleted
                                          select a)
                                              );
        }

        return HttpContext.Current.Application["Attendee.GetLiveByBookingId"] as Func<Entities, int, IQueryable<Attendee>>;
    }
```

Comment: get LinqPad and analyze the generated SQL

Comment: That's a ton of Includes! Is there any way you can project this down to a simpler object type that suits the needs of the view more directly?

Comment: @DLeh LinqPad is awesome

Comment: How many records is it returning?

Comment: It's returning one record relating to the BookingId. Still playing around with Linqpad. Pretty sure it needs all those includes, just an old system and that's how it was built.